# Merging multiple html saved as xls in a table in R

Tags: r, merge

I have a folder with multiple html files with .xls extension.

[data sample](http://%20%20%5B1%5D:%20http://www.filedropper.com/20190916)

I need to combine them in a single table:

I have started with reading files in a folder:

```
library(rvest)
library(tibble)

file_list <- list.files(pattern = '*.xls')

html_df <- lapply(file_list,function(x)read_html(x))
```

I do not know how to proceed from here to pull tables from each file and combine together

Comment: Upload the HTML files for us to give it a try.

Comment: are they **html** or **xls** files?

Comment: I'm with @rodolfoksveiga ... if the files are named `*.xls`, then it's most likely that they are Excel files (legacy-format). Try `df <- lapply(file_list, readxl::read_xls)`.

Comment: @xwhitelight I have just uploaded the sample. I can read the files with read_html but not with read_xls. It seems the content is html but the extension is .xls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if all the files have the same format as the sample you've uploaded:

```
library(rvest)

file_list <- list.files(pattern = '*.xls')
data <- 
  purrr::map_dfr( # use map_dfr() to combine data frames
    file_list,
    function(x) {
      read_html(x) %>%
        html_node("table") %>% # read the first 'table' node (which is the only one in the sample)
        html_table(fill = T) %>% # fill it because the table is not neat yet
        setNames(.[1, ]) %>% # use the first row to set column names
        .[-c(1, nrow(.)), ] # chop the first row which is the repeated column names and the last row which is the total row
    }
  )
```